# How to switch positive/negative voltage to positive voltage

Tags: led, voltage, dc

I have DIY telephone line powered flashlight (similar to [this post](http://lifehacker.com/5811528/make-a-diy-phone-line+powered-flashlight-for-your-next-power-outage), but I have used LED strip). The positive & negative leads seems to get updated frequently. Since I soldered the leads to LED strip, it doesn't work if the +ve /-ve leads are swapped.

Is there a way to swap the +ve and -ve if they are in wrong order with simple circuit/component?

[image: expected]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you may actually need a bridge rectifier - it converts any polarity DC (or cyclic ac) into the same polarity: -

[image]

You can buy them as one lump with 4 leads or make them from individual diodes - make sure the voltage rating on the diodes is high though - I'd choose at least 1000V rated diodes because telephone lines do have a tendency to get induced voltages from nearby lightning strikes.

Answer (score 3):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqMM8d.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You just need a bridge rectifier. Use the two AC input pins to connect to the input voltage and connect the '+' and '-' leads to your circuit. If the voltage drop across the diodes is higher than you would like, make your own bridge out of Schottky diodes.

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for a voltage inverter?

http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Make-a-Voltage-Inverter/

Comment: although this may not be the "simple" result youre looking for

Comment: See the much simple answers by others about bridge rectifiers.